# Show / Hide menu bar dynamically in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular2-routing, angular2-services

I'm currently working on a Angular 2 project. I implemented two components (1. header and 2. display page content).
If I open the service, I start with login / register. At this time, I want to hide all other menu items. 
If I'm logged-in, I want to show all menu items.

Currently, I'm using *ngIf to show and hide the the menu items, what actually works. My problem is, that if I start the page and I'm not logged-in, the menu items aren't there (this is fine). However, if I login, just the container with the page content is changing the content and not the menu bar...

Currently, I check if I'm logged in or not in this way:

```html
<div *ngIf="user != null">
...menu items...
</div>
```

This works if I reload the whole page - but I think there should be a nicer way to display / hide the menu items in real time without manual refreshing?

Could you kindly help me how I can solve this issue?

Comment: .@CodingMole- Please provide more details with relevant code, examples of what you tried and relevant screenshots. You also need to structure your question [in better way](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: `angularjs` is angular based on javascript, ie: version 1x. `Angular` is angular rewritten in TypeScript, ie: version 2 and 4. Please use the appropriate product name/terminology and tags for your question.

Comment: Thank you for answering. I have a header where I display the menu items. If I login in the main frame (other component), I want to display more specific user related menu items.

Currently, I check if I'm logged in or not in this way:

<div *ngIf="user != null">
...menu items...
</div>

This works if I reload the whole page - but I think there should be a nicer way to display / hide the menu items in real time without manual refreshing?

Comment: After login reset the `user` variable using a common service. Without showing how `user` is connected to the component(s) and service(s) there is nothing anyone can do for you because we would all be guessing at what you have.

Comment: Can you create a plunker with your code samples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably create a global user service which tracks user state and that components can subscribe to in order to always have a real time updates regarding where the user is logged in or not.

If you don't like the ngif solution at that point, you have a few options: you can create an entirely new component and display that in a route that is only accessible when the user is logged in, or you can do something like create a menu items array that controls your navigation menu items and run an ngfor.

Questions you should answer for more help are things like where are you currently tracking user state (your user variable) and how are components being notified of this variable changing? Just by guessing, you are probably setting the user variable based on local storage in a constructor or oninit function in your header and then leaving it. This will cause it to get the value of user one time but not update it later, which is why it will properly display on page refresh.